# CodeMirror custom binding doesn't work inside "foreach" binding

Tags: knockout.js, codemirror

I have created a custom binding for CodeMirror. Custom binding works with a simple string, but inside `foreach` binding, it ceases to be initialized, although all the HTML and CSS is added.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
var viewModel = {
  options: {
    mode: "text/x-csharp",
    lineNumbers: true
  },

  //IT WORKS
  fileContent: "public sealed class DictionaryAttribute : Attribute{}1",

  //IT DOESN'T WORK
  codes: ["public sealed class DictionaryAttribute : Attribute{}1"]
};

ko.bindingHandlers.codemirror = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var options = viewModel.options || {};
    options.value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    var editor = CodeMirror(element, options);

    editor.on('change', function(cm) {
      var value = valueAccessor();
      value(cm.getValue());
    });

    element.editor = editor;
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/clike/clike.js"></script>

<!-- This works -->
<div data-bind="codemirror: fileContent" style="width: 700px; height: 100px"></div>

<!-- This doesn't work -->
<div data-bind="foreach: codes">
  <div data-bind="codemirror: $data" style="width: 700px; height: 100px"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `var options = viewModel.options || {};` in your custom binding. `viewModel` parameter refers to the current `$data` in context, not the viewModel used in `applyBindings`. It works for a simple string because in that case, `viewModel` parameter *is* the main `viewModel` object you're passing to `applyBidnigs`. Inside `foreach`, `viewModel` will be each `$data` in your array.

So, use the `$root` property of [`bindingContext`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html#the-update-callback) parameter instead. Besides, `viewModel` parameter is deprecated in Knockout 3.x:

Like this:
`var options = bindingContext.$root.options || {};`

Updated snippet:

```js
var viewModel = {
  options: {
    mode: "text/x-csharp",
    lineNumbers: true
  },

  //IT WORKS
  fileContent: "public sealed class DictionaryAttribute : Attribute{}1",

  //IT DOESN'T WORK
  codes: ["public sealed class DictionaryAttribute : Attribute{}1"]
};

ko.bindingHandlers.codemirror = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var options = bindingContext.$root.options || {};
    options.value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    var editor = CodeMirror(element, options);

    editor.on('change', function(cm) {
      var value = valueAccessor();
      value(cm.getValue());
    });

    element.editor = editor;
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/clike/clike.js"></script>

<div data-bind="codemirror: fileContent" style="width: 700px; height: 100px"></div>

<div data-bind="foreach: codes">
  <div data-bind="codemirror: $data" style="width: 700px; height: 100px"></div>
</div>
```

---

The above code works in your case. But, the binding **expects** the top `$root` object to have the `options` property. Another way to do this would be to add a `codeMirrorOptions` parameter to the binding and remove that dependency altogether.

```js
var viewModel = {
  options: {
    mode: "text/x-csharp",
    lineNumbers: true
  },

  //IT WORKS
  fileContent: "public sealed class DictionaryAttribute : Attribute{}1",

  //IT DOESN'T WORK
  codes: ["public sealed class DictionaryAttribute : Attribute{}1"]
};

ko.bindingHandlers.codemirror = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    // use allBindings
    var options = ko.unwrap(allBindings().codeMirrorOptions) || {};
    options.value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    var editor = CodeMirror(element, options);

    editor.on('change', function(cm) {
      var value = valueAccessor();
      value(cm.getValue());
    });

    element.editor = editor;
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/clike/clike.js"></script>

<div data-bind="codemirror: fileContent, codeMirrorOptions:options" style="width: 700px; height: 100px"></div>

<div data-bind="foreach: codes">
  <div data-bind="codemirror: $data, codeMirrorOptions:$parent.options" style="width: 700px; height: 100px"></div>
</div>
```

In this case, the custom binding is independent of the viewModel. Even if your `viewModel` isn't the `$root` object, the custom binding will work.